# Avoiding circular dependencies in Spring beans with list properties

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

Let's say that I have a Maven project using the Spring framework. The Maven project itself has three modules: `common`, `component_a`, and `component_b`. And let's say that `common` defines an event listener bean with a property `listeners`, which is a list of everything listening for events. Listeners are defined in the `component_a` and `component_b` modules.

To summarize:

applicationcontext-component_a.xml:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="someListener" class="com.whatever.component_a.SomeListener"/>
    <bean id="anotherListener" class="com.whatever.component_a.AnotherListener"/>
</beans>
```

applicationcontext-component_b.xml:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="yetAnotherListener" class="com.whatever.component_b.YetAnotherListener"/>
</beans>
```

applicationcontext-common.xml:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="eventListener" class="com.whatever.common.EventListenerImpl">
        <property name="listeners">
            <list>
                <ref bean="someListener"/>
                <ref bean="anotherListener"/>
                <ref bean="yetAnotherListener"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

(I think I got the format right here...but forgive me if I didn't)

My problem is that now `common` has a dependency on both of the `component_*` modules, instead of the other way around. My `common` module no longer builds properly, because my integration tests cannot properly create the container without those other modules.

So given the fact that my `eventListener` needs to have a list of all of its listeners, what's a good pattern to use that will keep my modules independent during building/testing?

I can think of a few patterns:

1. Using different versions of `eventListener` within different
   contexts
2. Using a new bean to facilitate the registration
3. Inside each
   `setEventListener()` call, remember to call
   `eventListener.addListener(this);`

But I'm curious if Spring has any built-in way of doing this better...

Comment: How do you `import` your contexts?

Comment: You really shouldn't have anything explicit in your `common` base module; use some sort of packaging module instead, and you can inject a list of component-scanned beans in any case.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis We don't use imports at all... We have several contexts for production (via web.xml) and our integration test suites, and there are circular dependencies everywhere, but each one is complete as far as Spring is concerned... The net effect is that the project builds fine, but the modules can't be built independently.

Comment: @chrylis I do actually have a module that packages the WAR (let's say that it's `component_b`). But it uses context configuration from XML files inside both itself and the `common` module. Is that a bad practice?

Comment: Not per se, but if you're doing something like explicitly assembling a list of listeners instead of scanning it, that definitely shouldn't be in your `common` module. Follow the same rules in Spring wiring that you do in Maven dependencies.

Comment: "instead of scanning it" ...I think scanning for listeners is my best approach here. Where can I find more information on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do instead is autowiring a list of listeners in your main module. Each other module can then just provide implementations of this interface and a proper componentscan/xml declaration.

Mainmodule: (pseudocode)

```
@Service
ListenerService {

    @Autowire
    List<ListenerIntf> listeners;

    public handleListeners() {
        foreach listeners {
            listener.onEvent();
        }
    }
}
```

Module 1:

```
@Component
@Order // if desired
Listener1 implements ListenerIntf {
    public onEvent();
}
```

Comment: And Spring will automatically populate the `listeners` property with every implementation it finds of `ListenerIntf`?

Comment: Yes. All implementations of the interface will be wired. Additionally to that you can even use the "Order" annotation to automatically order that list. (in spring 4)